# Broken Package when trying to install libminiupnpc-dev

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, ppa

I'm not sure how to resolve the following broken package errors.  I have libminiupnpc8 installed from a PPA (1.6-precise2) and when I want to install libminiupnpc-dev, it wants to install libminiupnpc8 (1.6-3ubuntu1) from the standard repository.  What's the best way to resolve this?  Can I set a precedent in the repository list so it will take the Ubuntu one before the private one?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libminiupnpc-dev : Depends: libminiupnpc8 (= 1.6-3ubuntu1) but 1.6-precise2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f` (-f: "Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is, if those needed packages are in the Official Ubuntu [Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com), remove that PPA and install needed packages.

It seems that the `libminiupnpc-dev` that going to be installed from the Main repository, not from the PPA. If you want to use that repository somehow, you have to do [Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto). That means you need gain a higher position to that PPA in installation. To do that run this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

Then add following lines to the *Gedit* and save:

```
Package: libminiupnpc-dev
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: libminiupnpc-dev
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-<ppa name>
Pin-Priority: 200
```

** Replace < ppa name > with that PPA name(without phrase *ppa:*)

Comment: so what would the PPA name be?